# Clarification regarding Qing Han elliptic PDE theorem 4.9

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

In the line $\int \xi^2|D(logu)|^2\leq C\int|D(\xi)|^2$ I really don't understand how the RHS i.e $C\int |D(\xi)|^2$ is coming. Any help would be really really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Are the coefficients bounded by something you can allow in the constant? I can't remember the exact hypotheses here but I think it is a classic case of the inequality $ab < \tfrac{1}{2}(a^2 + b^2)$ used in some form. In fact the correct form may be something more like
$$
ab \leq \epsilon a^2 + \frac{1}{\epsilon}b^2,
$$
if you need to absorb the $a^2$ term back into the LHS. This seems to be used in elliptic PDE all the time. I think they essentially have done something like
$$
\sum_{i,j}\zeta a_{ij}\tfrac{1}{u}D_iu D_j\zeta = \sum_{i,j} \bigl(\sqrt{a_{ij}} D_j\zeta\bigr)\bigl(\zeta\sqrt{ a_{ij}}(D\log u)_i\bigr)
$$
$$
\leq \sum_{i,j}\bigl(\epsilon\ \zeta^2a_{ij}|(D\log u)_i|^2  + \frac{1}{\epsilon}a_{ij} |D_j\zeta|^2 \bigr).
$$

Comment: Yes $a_{ij}'s$ are in $L^{\infty}(B_1)$ and satisfies $\lambda |\xi|^2\leq a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\leq \Lambda |\xi|^2$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and $x\in B_1$. And thanks yes we use it everywhere but here God knows why I didn't realize it.

Comment: I have one more thing to clarify if you can help. When in the next line we are choosing the cutoff $\xi=1$ in $B_1$ . Then LHS is becoming $\int_{B_1} |D(log u)|^2$ but isn't the R.HS is becoming zero as $\xi$ is identically $1$ in $B_1$ so $D(\xi)=0$ but then how this $C$ is coming in the RHS?

Comment: The test function will be compactly supported in $B_2$ so there is still some unavoidable positive contribution on the right-hand side